# ng-init not working with ng-app causing uncaught error 38

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular.js here is my code

`<div class="heading"  ng-app="myapp" ng-init="heading='11'">
 <h2>{{heading}}</h2>
 </div>`

If I use ng-app="" it works fine, but the above code doesn't work,
I'm using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js
I wonder why is that?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: On the other hand, putting things in the root scope is a design smell, and ng-init is explicitly documented as "you should never use ng-init, except in a very very particular condition", so... Just forget that ng-init exists, use controllers, and initialize the state of the controller in the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` is a [directive for auto-bootstrapping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) an Angular application. It accepts a module as parameter. You should define your `myapp` module if you want to use it.

1) Create a file called `app.js`

2) Define the `myapp` module

```
angular
  .module('myapp', []);
```

3) Add `app.js` after the Angular JS core

`<script src="app.js"></script>`

4) Now you can use `myapp` module as a parameter in `ng-app` directive